# Firebase: How to get document in sub collection without the parent key

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I need to perform a query to get the oldest document in a sub collection.
I want to perform this query with few reads as possible.
DB description:
Based on Firebase.
Collection of devices. Each device holds a collection of call-backs. For a specific device I need to fetch the oldest call-back (call-backs has timestamp).

I think I know how to perform this query using the device Unique ID, But I want to do it by filtering by some field of the device, **this field is also unique**.
I was able to do it by querying the device with all of his call-backs but this will charge me for more reads then actually needed.

Query that works using ID:

```
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("devices/{device_id}/callbacks")
    .{order_by_timestamp}
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      let callbacks = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        callbacks.push(doc.data());
      });

      return res.json(callbacks);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that field in devices collection is unique then you can fetch ID of that device first and then proceed with your existing logic as shown below:

```
async function getOldestCallback(thatFieldValue) {
  const device = await admin.firestore().collection("devices").where("thatField", "==", thatFieldValue).get()

  if (device.empty) return false;
  
  const deviceId = device[0]["id"];

  // existing function
}
```

This should incur 2 reads (1 for device document and 1 for oldest callback if it exist).

Additionally, since you are limiting number of docs to be returned to 1 then you can use `[0]` instead of using a forEach loop.

```
const callbacks = [ data[0].data() ]
```

Comment: Ok.
So there is no way to perform this query in one read operation without knowing the device id in advance?

Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Ofir one way would be to store that field in callback document as well and then use collection group query.. `admin.firestore().collectionGroup("callbacks").where(....)`. Just chain multiple `where()` for multiple fields

Comment: Good idea.
Another idea I had is to use the devices unique field as the device ID (Technically its not causing problems). The problem is that the client knows this field. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use it as ID if the client knows about it.

Comment: @Ofir I'm not totally sure about what the use case it, but if clients already know it then what's the issue? You can use security rules so only allowed users can access data if needed.

Comment: Maybe the right way is like you said. Using the unique field as ID instead of firebase random ID and use security rules to limit access.